# Select data from one table. Then using that data to get info from another table

Tags: mysql, database

I have two tables.

**First one**
Focus on the `UserID` and `AssignID`.
[image]

**Second one** Focus on `id`.
[image]

Okay so what I want to do is that, there is a textbox to key in your userId. So for example, a person keys in Spongebob. Then in the first table, Spongebob's `assignID` is "2". Then I want to use this "2" to display all the information from the second table `id=2`.

How do I do that ?

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Hint `INNER JOIN`.    Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Comment: This question has exactly zero to do with C#. Please don't add irrelevant tags. What language you're writing an application in is irrelevant. Add tags that relate specifically tot he question you're asking only.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I am going to code it in c#

Comment: No you're not, unless you're going to use EF or the like, which you have made no reference to. If you're querying a database then you're doing it in SQL.  The fact that that SQL code may be sent to the database from an app written in C# is irrelevant because the SQL would be the same no matter what language the app was written in.  Does the recipe for making a cake depend on what store you bought the ingredients from or how you transported them home?

Comment: Okay I understand now

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple inner join where you only project columns from the child table, e.g.

```sql
SELECT e.*
FROM assign a INNER JOIN exercise1 e
ON a.assignID = e.id
WHERE a.userId = :userId
```

Comment: what does `e.*` means ?

Comment: You're using `*` in your own SQL in those screen shots.  I said "only project columns from the child table" in my answer.  I also used `e.id`. in the SQL I posted.  You have all the information you need to figure that out for yourself.  I'm here to help with the difficult stuff, not teach the basics of SQL.  I expect people to look first and ask questions later.